ExcelScript / Office360/ Javascript : Loop copies range 4 times instead of adjustedN - SOLVED
I'm working with ExcelScript and encountering an issue with a loop that copies a range of cells. The loop is intended to copy the range adjustedN times, where adjustedN is calculated as Math.floor((numberOfPages - 16) / 2). However, the loop always copies the range 4 times regardless of the calculated value of adjustedN. I don't know how to fix it, because the calculation is correct.
I'd like that range be copied AdjustedN times as the looping and don't 4 times always, dont matter N value.
// Calculate the adjusted number of iterations ((N-16)/2)
const adjustedN = Math.floor((numberOfPages - 16) / 2);

const startColumn = 2; // Column B
const startRow = 41;
const endColumn = 59; // Column BH 
let currentColumn = startColumn;
let currentRow = startRow;

let pageCounter = 0;

// Get the destination range 
const destinationRange = copiedSheet.getRangeByIndexes(currentRow - 1, currentColumn - 1, 14, 52); // Assuming the template range is 14 rows by 52 columns

// Use a for loop to copy the range adjustedN times
for (let i = 0; i < adjustedN; i++) {
// Copy values and formatting from the template range
destinationRange.copyFrom(templateSheet.getRange(rangeToCopyForN16), ExcelScript.RangeCopyType.all);
// Increment page numbers for the copied range
incrementPagNumbers(copiedSheet, destinationRange.getAddress(), 15 + pageCounter, 1);
pageCounter++;
}

Update  include the SOLUTION to who have similar problem, that is copy part of a range N times in a space pre-selected
 // Calculate the adjusted number of iterations ((N-16)/2)
    const adjustedN = Math.ceil((numberOfPages - 16) / 2);

    const startColumn = 1; // Column A
    const startRow = 5;
    const endColumn = 10; // Column J (inclusive)
    const templateWidth = 3; // Template range width in columns
    const templateHeight = 4; // Template range height in rows
    const groupsPerRow = 3; // Number of groups that fit in a row

    // Extra space after each group (adjust as needed, currently 1)
    const extraSpace = 0;

    // Initialize target row and column before the loop (important for correct starting position)
    let targetRow = startRow;
    let targetColumn = startColumn;

    // Initialize page counter - in my case, I use it to change the number later and have written Pag 1, Pag 2, Pag N...  
    let pageCounter = 0;

    // Loop for the adjusted number of copies
    for (let i = 0; i < adjustedN; i++) {
      // Check if the next column exceeds the limit OR we reach the group limit for the row
      if ((targetColumn - startColumn) / templateWidth >= groupsPerRow) {
        // Move to the next row, ensuring enough space for groupsPerRow
        targetRow += templateHeight; // Adjust based on template height to include the last group in the row and reduce vertical space
        targetColumn = startColumn;
      }

      // Get the destination range
      const destinationRange = copiedSheet.getRangeByIndexes(targetRow - 1, targetColumn - 1, templateHeight, templateWidth);

      // Copy values and formatting from the template range
      destinationRange.copyFrom(templateSheet.getRange(rangeToCopyForN16), ExcelScript.RangeCopyType.all);

      // Increment page numbers for the copied range (the function exists)
      incrementPagNumbers(copiedSheet, destinationRange.getAddress(), pageCounter++, 1); //function only to white Pag N with the right numbers

      // Update target column for next iteration
      targetColumn += templateWidth + extraSpace; // Account for extra space

      pageCounter++; //the counter to Pag N
    }


Please share the code of incrementPagNumbers. What's it for?

only to increment the Pag. like a real book ,when create more copies, you add the number of pages. its working. ""

The destinationRange remains unchanged within the for loop, causing the later copying to overwrite the earlier copying. Is this the intended behavior?

No, is to create N copies , but you give me a way to fix it , that I didnt noticed before. thanks
